# Python regex get string between quotes

Tags: python, regex, string, quotes, between

I'm trying to write a tiny python script for localising source code files.

In the source files there are some strings such as this one:

```
title: "Warning".localized()
```

What I'm trying to do is extracting the string between the quotes whenever I find a `.localized()` attached.

The regex for matching this strings is: `regex = re.compile('([^"]*).localized\(\)', re.DOTALL)`

The matching works because I get the following output:

```
...
./testproject/test1.swift
.localized()
.localized()
./testproject/test2.swift
...
```

But what I don't get is the string between the quotes.

The python script:

```
import os, re, subprocess
import fnmatch

def fetch_files_recursive(directory, extension):
matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*' + extension):
      matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
return matches

regex = re.compile('([^"]*).localized\(\)', re.DOTALL)

for file in fetch_files_recursive('.', '.swift'):
print file
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    # e.g. "Warning".localized(),
    for result in regex.finditer(content):
        print result.group(0) // output = '.localized()'
        print result.group(1) // output = '' empty :-(
```

Comment: The regex should probably be more like `/"([^"]+)"\.localized\(\)/`. You're not allowing for the `"` in between `Warning` and `.localized`. And since you use an asterisk group 1 will be empty.

Comment: Try: `regex = re.compile(r'"([^"]*)"\.localized\(\)')` and use captured group #1

Comment: Also, for future reference, this site is great for testing Python regex: http://pythex.org

Comment: @anubhava thanks, it worked. Post it as a answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment into answer.

You can use this pattern:

```
regex = re.compile(r'"([^"]*)"\.localized\(\)')
```

and use captured group #1. `[^"]*` matches 0 or more of any char that is not a double quote.

Or using arounds:

```
regex = re.compile(r'(?<=")([^"]*)"(?="\.localized\(\)'))
```